# Confusion regarding price difference in two laptops

Tags: laptop, processor, hard-disk

I have been considering buying a new laptop and got puzzled regarding price differences between this two models:

1. [HP Envy 13-ah0042tu 2018 13.3-inch Laptop (8th Gen Intel Core i3-8130U/4GB/128GB/Windows 10 Home/Integrated Graphics), Natural Silver
   by HP](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07FGFCM3J/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_x4Q9CbDN5MSN1)

Price: ₹ 56,990.0

2. [HP 14-inch Core i5 8th Gen FHD Laptop (8GB/1TB HDD/Win 10/Integrated Graphics/MS Office/Natural Silver/1.43 kg), 14s-cs1000tu](https://www.amazon.in/HP-14-inch-Integrated-Graphics-14s-cs1000tu/dp/B07LDRVXKX/ref=mp_s_a_1_5)

Price: ₹ 47,990.00

*The prices are as shown on amazon.in*

The second model has greater hard disk space, more RAM (8GB compared to 4GB of the first model), has better processor (i5 comapred to i3 of first model) and also larger screen size.
Despite this it costs around 11000 lower than the first one.

What am I missing in comparison between this two models? I am tempted to go for the second model but cautious that I might miss something significant which I would have in first model (because of indication of price differences).

I would like to understand this dilemma.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a comparison between two laptops.

Comment: Instead of asking what the difference between two laptops are, list out your requirements and describe how you will use the system and we will find the perfect laptop that fits your budget and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

One difference which immediately springs out is that the first model has a [Solid State Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) (sized 128GB) while the second one has an 'old-fashioned' Hard Disk Drive. That one is as you noted, 8 times larger, but much cheaper.

The type of hard disk makes a huge difference these days. Exact figures will depend on what you're doing with the laptop, but [here](http://www.risharde.com/blog/windows-10-ssd-vs-normal-hard-disk-boot-times.html) is a random example where Windows 10 boots 3.5 times faster on an SSD than on an HDD.

I'm not sure if a 128GB is sufficient for your purposes, but personally I wouldn't buy a computer without an SSD anymore. Some laptop models might have room for a second hard drive, so that you can store large files (e.g. photos) on a separate drive, but I'm not sure how common that is these days and whether these models support it.

Comment: Considering that it is a hard drive, it is probably user replaceable. With 2.5” SSDs being so cheap these days, buying the cheaper laptop and then upgrading the hard drive to an SSD would be a pretty good option.

Comment: Yes. Customer reviews on second model do say that its booting time is around 40 s. I wanted to ask another question regarding what you mentioned about performance differences between SSD and HDD. Given that I want to use the laptop specifically for academic purposes and not for gaming or coding, what difference would the two models make for me?